# Access value of an entity attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

I have a Core Data to-many relationship that looks like this:

`Athlete(evals)<->>Eval(whosEval)`

I have a table view for Athletes which displays ALL the Athletes in the database. I want to set the subtitle text to a Eval attribute, let's say it is called "date_recorded" the problem is, there could be more than 1 eval for each Athlete. I need to select the last object in the evalArray, and then display the correlating Eval attribute for each Athlete, so each Athlete's subtitle text will probably be different. How would I do this for every cell in my table? Here is what i've got so far:

allathletes.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Athlete Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Athlete *athlete = (Athlete *)[athleteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text =[athlete full];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = //eval attribute "date_recorded"

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    _managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSFetchRequest *athleteRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    [athleteRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Athlete" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];
    NSError *athleteError = nil;
    NSPredicate *athletePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"full == %@", athlete.full];
    [athleteRequest setPredicate:athletePredicate];
    NSArray *results = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:athleteRequest error:&athleteError];
    Athlete *currentAthlete = [results objectAtIndex:0];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whosEval == %@", currentAthlete];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSEntityDescription *eval = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Eval" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:eval];



    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor =
    [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date_recorded"
                                ascending:NO
                                 selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil){
        //handle error
    }

    NSMutableArray *lastEvalArray = mutableFetchResults;

Eval *lastEval = lastEvalArray.lastObject;

cell.detailTextLabel.text = lastEval.date_recorded;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `date_recorded` is an `NSDate` attribute, then you can just do

```
Athlete *athlete = (Athlete *)[athleteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSDate *lastRecorded = [athlete valueForKeyPath:@"@max.evals.date_recorded"];
```

and then use a `NSDateFormatter` to convert `lastRecorded` to an `NSString` and
assign it to `cell.detailTextLabel.text`.

Comment: @user2674329: How is the string formatted? To find the last date, they must be compared/sorted somehow. (That would be easier with NSDate objects.)

Comment: It has the value of a date, but is a string. Like so: "August 18, 2013". It is properly sorted.

Comment: @user2674329: There *is no ordering* for related objects (unless you used a *ordered* relationship, which has other problems). I can only recommend to store dates as dates, not as strings, and convert them to strings only for display. That makes most things much easier.

Comment: that is what I do. sorry if I explained that in a confusing way.